# Hide Smart Device winform without exit

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, smart-device

I want a winform from a smart device project (VS2008) to hide or get minimized to be opened later.

I need something like this.

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

Please help.

Comment: not clear on what you want.

Comment: @KingKing i want that the program get minimized.